# Data Table with custom select box not working

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I am displaying data table in the web page, I want to add an additional filter to get results based on `clinic name` I got data table displayed and all other functionalities like searching, sorting work fine but column filtering is not working

Following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

I refereed this from [https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html]

But why values are not showing,

Is there are any other options to add Select drop-down to show values of clinic name from PHP database, and on clicking that I want to filter the data on the table

- https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether your table have `<tfoot>` this require tfoot element to works